# Running Basic Laravel Task in Routes.php - "Sorry, can't find that task."

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to setup a Laravel task to eventually be called as a cron job using the artisan interface.

In trying to get a simple task working, I keep getting the error that Laravel can't find that task: "Sorry, can't find that task."

Is this a problem with my version? I'm using a version downloaded less than a month ago which I know is at least v3.0 but I don't know how to check the specific version number.

Is there something I need to configure in start.php to register all my "Tasks"? I thought this was done by default for all classes saved in /application/tasks

Mytask.php

```
class Mytask_Task {

    public function run($arguments) {
        // Do awesome notifying...
        echo "Hello from Mytask Task";
    }
}
```

Routes.php

```
try{
    \Laravel\CLI\Command::run(array('mytask'));
    echo "Success";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that for the non-cli requests the application workflow of laravel does not autoload the CLI components.

This is why you have to do it like this:

```
require_once path('sys') . 'cli' . DS . 'dependencies' . EXT;
Laravel\CLI\Command::run(array('migrate', 'application'));
```

Comment: This isn't the issue as I was testing within a routes function and the CLI components were in fact loaded because the route being called was not a CLI request.... See my answer below.

Comment: Thank you! been searching for this as to why the standard command didn't work from my route!

Answer (score 1):

So I got to the bottom of this and it turns out to be a pretty frustrating error.

In the particular v3.x version of Laravel I'm using, the Tasks are not recognized by their lowercase/case insensitive names. I was pointed in the right direction by [this post](https://github.com/chalien/lara_admin/issues/6) on Github.

So I renamed `Mytask.php` to `mytask.php` and the Task executes fine.

If anyone knows how to check the version of Laravel I'm running so others can know if they are affected, please let me know and I'll update this post.